# C code working perfectly on linux but not on MacOS

Tags: c, macos, terminal

This code works perfectly on Linux, but returns the error "gethostbyname: Undefined error: 0" in the terminal. I have also tried other codes from the net, but all of them either return some error during compilation or display the IPv4 address as 0.0.0.0. Is there anything I can do to make this work?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

void checkHostName(int hostname)
{
    if (hostname == -1) {
        perror("gethostname");
        exit(1);
    }
}

void checkHostEntry(struct hostent* hostentry)
{
    if (hostentry == NULL) {
        perror("gethostbyname");
        exit(1);
    }
}

void checkIPbuffer(char* IPbuffer)
{
    if (NULL == IPbuffer) {
        perror("inet_ntoa");
        exit(1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    char hostbuffer[256];
    char* IPbuffer;
    struct hostent* host_entry;
    int hostname;

    hostname = gethostname(hostbuffer, sizeof(hostbuffer));
    checkHostName(hostname);

    host_entry = gethostbyname(hostbuffer);
    checkHostEntry(host_entry);

    IPbuffer = inet_ntoa(*((struct in_addr*) host_entry->h_addr_list[0]));

    printf("Hostname: %s\n", hostbuffer);
    printf("Host IP: %s", IPbuffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: have you considered removing some new lines from your code? PS: on macos 10.15.5 it works fine

Comment: `gethostbyname()` doesn't set `errno`, so using it with `perror()` is kind of strange.

Comment: Suggestion: *The `gethostbyname*()` and `gethostbyaddr*()` functions are obsolete. Applications should use getaddrinfo(3) and getnameinfo(3) instead.* --- from https://linux.die.net/man/3/gethostbyname

Comment: @FredLarson That's `gethostname`, the question is about `gethostbyname`

Comment: @Barmar: Ah, the code in question uses both. Easy to confuse them.

Comment: @Jeff: Why don't you simplify the code even further. Does `gethostbyname("google.com")` work?

Comment: Your code works fine for me, running on a Mac with Mojave as the OS.  Tried both in Xcode and from the terminal.

Comment: Copied the executable to a Catalina system and it runs there too.

Comment: What's the hostname?  What's the value of `h_errno` after `gethostbyname()` fails? What happens if you do an `nslookup hostname` from the command line on your Linux system?